# How to output specific strings in a text file using powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-ise

I have a.txt and b.txt.
A.txt contains {2b,3c,5e,8h}, B.txt contains {1a,2b,3c,4d,5e,6f}

I would like to compare those two files, and out put only what a.txt have,i.e. "8h".

I have tried Compare-Object command. But it gives out the differences. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the data is formatted exactly as above, you can use:

```
$a = '{2b,3c,5e,8h}'
$b = '{1a,2b,3c,4d,5e,6f}'

Compare-Object -ReferenceObject  $a.Trim('}', '{').Split(',') -DifferenceObject $b.Trim('}', '{').Split(',') | Where-Object {$_.SideIndicator -eq '<='}
```

Of course you will need to use `Get-Content` to read the contents of your file into `$a` and `$b`

Comment: @Han please mark it as the answer if it helped you, so others can benefit as well.